# Отображение тела AJAX запросов

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

Несколько раз сталкивался с отслеживанием и отладкой тела отправленной и полученной информации при помощи AJAX. Сейчас работаю с `datatables`, где все и работает с этим делом. Очень хороший пример - https://editor.datatables.net/examples/simple/multiRow.html.
Перейдите на вкладку `Ajax data`, а потом выберете один или несколько рядов и отредактируйте их (кнопка `Edit`). Сразу появится информация о том, что было отправлено (`Submitted data`) и получено (`Received data`). Собственно вопрос: Как сделать такой вывод информации, когда нужно сделать отладку (в идеале кусок кода, который можно подключать к разным страницам)? П.С. Работаю в PHP

Comment: В консоли хрома можно посмотреть запрос и ответ от сервера, свои запросы можно формировать в Postman.

Comment: Именно тело запроса? Как?

Comment: в общем случае - никак. Нужен вывод именно для datatables? Хотя возможно помогут [глобальные обработчики из jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/)

Comment: Ну сейчас надо для datatables, хотя в перспективе не только

Comment: @tekken, на видео можно посмотреть https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOQDrGrd9H8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@tekken, на видео можно посмотреть youtube.com/watch?v=WOQDrGrd9H8 – Marsel Arduanov`
Спасибо, очень полезная штука! То, что надо!

Answer (score 0):

не совсем ясно как отправляешь ajax - native js или JQuery ?

Пишешь в коде строчку "debugger;" Открываешь хром, нажимаешь F12 запускаешь скрипт.
у тебя запуститься консоль отладки, добавляешь в Watсh то что хочешь посмотреть , т.е  скажем перед вызовом ajax ты какието данные отправляешь, вот и вбиваешь эти переменные и видишь что в них, тоже самое и при приеме, у тебя есть функция которая вызывается при успешном ответе c сервера ставишь там debugger; и смотришь